# Google Professional Cloud Exam Question -high traffic / relational databases crashes/replica is never promoted to a master

Tags: google-cloud-platform, failover

During a high traffic portion of the day, one of your relational databases crashes, but the replica is never promoted to a master. You want to avoid this in the future.
What should you do?

A. Use a different database

B. Choose larger instances for your database

**C. Create snapshots of your database more regularly**

D. Implement routinely scheduled failovers of your databases

I feel that the answer should be 'C'.

Explanation:
Take regular snapshots of your database system.
If your database system lives on a Compute Engine persistent disk, you can take snapshots of your system each time you upgrade. If your database system goes down or you need to roll back to a previous version, you can simply create a new persistent disk from your desired snapshot and make that disk the boot disk for a new Compute Engine instance. Note that, to avoid data corruption, this approach requires you to freeze the database system's disk while taking a snapshot.
Reference: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/disaster-recovery-cookbook

**However, there are so many varied answers from other sources and now I am confused.**

Can someone please help? Thanks a zillion.

Answer (score 3):

To select the best answer you must determine what is the question. Questions often have key items that affect the best answer.

What is the question?

The question is how to avoid database crashes.

What are the key items in the question?

- High traffic
- Only during a portion of the day
- There is a replica
- The replica is not promoted

Do all of the key items apply? Sometimes key points are not relevant to the question to test your understanding. In this case, the replica is that item. None of the answers involve a replica. That leaves you with two key points:

- High traffic
- Only during a portion of the day

Of the four answers, eliminate the ones that do not apply to the question. These answers are not good answers to the key points of the question.

- Use a different database. Changing the database could mean significant changes to the application design. In most cases, this is not a good answer.
- Create snapshots of your data more regularly. Snapshots are for backup and recovery. They do not prevent database crashes. In fact, if snapshots are performed too often, for example, when the database is under heavy load, you are more likely to make the problem worse.
- implement routinely scheduled failover. This will not prevent a database from failing. This will help you recover after a failure.

That leaves one answer:

**Choose larger instances for your database**

Most database systems are not auto-scaling. That means you must select an instance size that can handle peak traffic loads. Only one of the answers provides for that fundamental requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The question being asked is how to avoid a replica not being promoted to primary, NOT how to avoid a crash.
The crux of the problem here is that the replica was not promoted.

Testing failover is would ensure that replica are in fact able to assume primary roles.

Comment: One flaw with your decision point. If the database is crashing because it is overloaded during peak times, promoting the replica, which is typically the same size or smaller, will also crash. If there is an increased backlog during the recovery time, the replica will have an even higher initial load compounding the problem. Testing failover should happen during the design and testing phase, not with running systems that are required for production.

Answer (score -1):

Very good analysis for cracking sometimes confusing exam questions.

However, the question doesn't seem to be about **avoiding crashes**. It is about avoiding **replicas not being promoted to master** after the crash. So in this case only D makes sense.

Comment: As any DBA will tell you, choosing D will probably get you fired.